# Can you in code find out what OutputCache VaryByParams values have been set on a page/control in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, outputcache

Given an `outputcache` directive like this on a page

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="Id" %>
```

How can I tell what the `VaryByParam` value is in code.

The `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByParams` object contains a private `_parameters` Dictionary and an internal `IsVaryByStar` property, but without reflecting into the object which I'm fairly loath to do, I can't access them.  Is there any standard way to discover what outputcache directives have been set on a particular request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there would be another way to enumerate parameters. Beside enumerating parameters, you may have to look out for wild-card(`"*"`) parameter. So I believe that the simplest way would be to use reflection.

On different note, I am not certain about exact use case that needs such requirement. Couple of alternative approaches may or may not suite you requirements are

1. Build your own control/extender to accept caching parameters (instead of OutputCache directive) and then modify Response.Cache in early page life cycle.
2. Use brute-force attack by building dictionary of all possible parameters (but wild-card support may spoil this because in such case `Response.Cache.Item` will return true for all parameters). Possible alternative is to force page to give its cache parameters by introducing an abstract method from base page class.